# Any equivalent to .= for adding to beginning of string in PHP?

Tags: php

Just wondering if there is something like .= for adding text to the beginning of a string, e.g.:

```
$foo =. 'bar';
```

which doesn't work.

Edit: example was originally `$foo =. $bar;` which can be achieved with `$bar .= $foo;`

Comment: I vouch for James' though he should have written an answer for it...

Comment: That appends `$foo` to `$bar`, instead of prepending `$bar` to `$foo`.  The result is similar, but I think he wants to mutate `$foo`.

Comment: It was meant to be a bit of a tongue-in-cheek comment (which is why it's a comment, not an answer)!

Comment: ugh... sorry, bad example... fixed now :)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Nope.  But you can do

```
$foo = "bar" . $foo
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always make your own function for that:

```
function prepend($string, $chunk) {
     if(!empty($chunk) && isset($chunk)) {
        return $string.$chunk;
     }
     else {
        return $string;
     }
}
```

`$string` would be the piece that you want to prepend and `$chunk` would be the text that you want something prepended onto it.

You could say the checks are optional, but by having that in there you don't need to worry about passing in a null value by accident.

Comment: Thanks, you are right though. It's definitely not as easy or fast as something built in. Feel free to copy and paste if that helps make it easier :D

Comment: If something is `!empty` it's also always `isset`, no need for this double check. Furthermore, since `$chunk` is a required parameter of the function, it *needs* to be passed to the function or PHP will complain. This means this check can be abbreviated to `if ($chunk)` (to see if it's *falsy* a.k.a. "empty"). But, if `$chunk` doesn't contain anything, nothing will happen anyway. So this whole function body can be abbreviated to `return $string . $chunk`. Which means this whole function is pretty unnecessary.

Comment: You can have a variable be set but also be empty. For example, a variable with the value of "" is empty but also set.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying your function is a very verbose way to write `$foo . $bar`. I challenge you to find any important case were your function does anything different. :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked/answered a while ago, but providing this answer as it is functionally equivalent despite it not being an assignment operator and no one commented on its usage for general string concatenation.

You may want to look into the use of the `sprintf` ([documentation](http://php.net/sprintf)) family of functions for string concatenation.
It provides a lot more sanitization and usability than just combining two strings with assignment operators.

```
$foo = 'foo';

$append = sprintf('%1$s%2$s', $foo, 'bar');
var_dump($append);
/* string(6) "foobar" */

$prepend = sprintf('%1$s%2$s', 'bar', $foo);
var_dump($prepend);
/* string(6) "barfoo" */

$prependInvert = sprintf('%2$s%1$s', $foo, 'bar');
var_dump($prependInvert);
/* string(6) "barfoo" */

$wrap = sprintf('%2$s%1$s%2$s', $foo, 'bar');
var_dump($wrap);
/* string(6) "barfoobar" */
```

I normally use `vsprintf`, since working with arrays is easier to manage value positions than individual arguments.

```
$vprepend = vsprintf('%2$s%1$s', array('foo', 'bar'));
var_dump($vprepend);
/* string(6) "barfoo" */
```

Also with an array of values, one can simply `implode` the resultant set of values for simple string concatenation.

```
 var_dump(implode('', array('bar', 'foo')));
 /* string(6) "barfoo" */
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think sprintf() is as fast as simple concats.  And it certainly doesn't seem nearly as syntax-friendly, either.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147305/2430549

Comment: Correct, though not sure how you mean by syntax friendly. While it is not as fast or simplistic as concatenation. `sprintf` is commonly used throughout multiple languages. `sprintf` has its place and purpose on when to use it. eg. casting of multiple values or enforcing a number of inputs using `sprintf`, provides you with more functionality than simple concatenation when is *required*. See: https://3v4l.org/8PWil But it should be not be used as a complete replacement for concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the built-in function `substr_replace`, where the arguments $start and $length can be set to 0, which prepends the $replacement to $string and returns the result, like so:

```
function prepend(& $string, $prefix) {
    $string = substr_replace($string, $prefix, 0, 0);
}
```

An example usage of the helper function would be:

```
$email_message = "Jonathan";
$appropriate_greeting = "Dear ";
prepend($email_message, $appropriate_greeting);
echo $email_message;
```

If you are into procedural programming, that is.

Comment: I don't see the interest of using substr_replace; doing a simple `$string = $prefix.$string;` in the function will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Turning [Blakethepatton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111841/445547#comment81028815_7111841) into an answer (thank you), a way to do this more neatly for longer variable names is by using a **reference** to the variable as follows:

```
$f = &$foo; $f = "bar{$f}";
```

This will save you typing over the [answer by Eric V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111841/445547#answer-7111841) if your original variable name is 12 characters or longer.

An alternative on one line:

```
$f = 'bar' . ($f = &$foo);
```