# How to show multiple specific columns from an array and display as one string

Tags: php, laravel

My array looks like this:

```
 {
        "fileinfo": {
        "database": "homestead",
        "git": "master",
        "date": 12,
        "year": 2018,
        "month": "October"
        }
 }
```

I want to pickup gitBranch, date, month, year from the array and print as

1 string

I tried vsprintf and sprintf, but cannot figured out.

Comment: Add your attempts to your question. There should be nothing difficult about concatenating strings together.

Comment: Try to json_decode it, that will result in an array of the data

Comment: @KoenHollander, I dont want an array. Its already an array. I want specific keys and values in one string.

Comment: @JonStirling The difficult part is not all the array but only specific columns

Comment: Pulling specific names key values shouldn't be difficult either, so again please add your attempted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have this array as `$array`

```
$str = sprintf('Branch: %s, Created: %s %s %s.', 
    $array['fileinfo']['gitBranch'],
    $array['fileinfo']['date'],
    $array['fileinfo']['month'],
    $array['fileinfo']['year']
);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "metadata" => array(),
    "fileinfo" =>array(
        "database" =>"homestead",
        "connection" => "mysql",
        "gitBranch" => "master",
        "minutes" => 41,
        "hours" => 13,
        "date" => 12,
        "year" => 2018,
        "month" => "October"
    )
 );

echo "Branch: {$array['fileinfo']['gitBranch']}, Created: {$array['fileinfo']['date']} {$array['fileinfo']['month']} {$array['fileinfo']['year']}";
```

This creates the output you desire.

For multiple arrays, do a `foreach()` through them with that inside, but obviously the `$array` variable will be whatever you set it to in the loop.

Comment: I liked the idea how @sietse85 used sprintf to combined them. but thx anyway

Comment: I also like it muchly! Will have to try and use it in future!

Comment: Also, might be worth you checking this out just for a more complete understanding of both solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147305/performance-of-variable-expansion-vs-sprintf-in-php which also links to this: http://judebert.com/progress/archives/204-PHP-String-Formatting-Performance.html which is all about PHP String Formatting Performance