# How to loop php sql output into a table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My code currently outputs the row by row from the information collected by an sql query.

The output looks like this at the moment:

```
First Name: test2 - Last Name: test2 - Appointment Time: 12041312
First Name: Jim - Last Name: Bob - Appointment Time: 13051130
First Name: John - Last Name: Smith - Appointment Time: 13051230
```

I am trying to sort it into a HTML table. Any help appreciated.

**Code for output:**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "First Name: " . $row["FirstName"]. " - Last Name: " . $row["LastName"]. " - Appointment Time: " . $row["AppTime"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results, please try again";
}
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY columname` to the query. Let MySQL do all the work for you

Comment: PS you can make that ECHO easier to read `echo "First Name: $row[FirstName] - Last Name: $row[LastName] - Appointment Time: $row[AppTime]<br>";`

Comment: yuk, i do not like that variable interpolation suggestion which you made.... @RiggsFolly it might be faster or slower on some PHP versions..But on PHP 7 this method seams to be [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917133/2548147), which i found wierd.. Edit oh there ` {$<...>}` was benchmarked which is different then variable interpolation

Comment: @RaymondNijland Had no idea on speed. Its just easier to read/maintain that all that concatenation

Comment: @RiggsFolly *"Had no idea on speed"* well it's micro optimisation really...  Anyhow *"Its just easier to read/maintain that all that concatenation "* i think i would even separate the single line on multiple lines grouped on fixed string and variable generated string value feels for me more readable and maintainable..

Comment: I mean into an actual html table using <th> ect.

Comment: Are you asking how to write some HTML to output data into an HTML table?

Comment: @RaymondNijland _"Had no idea on speed"_ means I did not even consider if it may have any effect on execution speed. _"think i would even separate the single line on multiple lines....."_ Absolutely agree. But I didnt want to take an obvious newbie and baffle them with anything more than they appeared to be capable of at the current place on their learning curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you have to add the data into a table.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Appointment Time</th>
        </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$row['FirstName']}</td>
                <td>{$row['LastName']}</td>
                <td>{$row['AppTime']}</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "No results, please try again";
}
```

If the issue is related to your query speed, please consider adding pagination. Or try to Index your DB table.